# The way to write ten thousand data points to InfluxDB per second

Tags: python, influxdb

I’m using a raspberry pi 4 to collect sensor data with a python script.

Like:

```
val=mcp.read_adc(0)
```

Which can read ten thousand data per second.

And now I want to save these data to influx for real-time analysis.

I have tried to save them to a log file while reading, and then use telegraf to collect as this [blog](https://www.iotforall.com/iot-dashboard) did:

But it’s not working for my stream data as it is too slow.

Also I have tried to use python's influxdb module to write directly, like:

```
client.write(['interface,path=address,elementss=link value=3.14'],{'db':'db'},204,'line')
```

It's worse.

So how can I write these data into influxdb in time. Are there any solutions?

Thank you much appreciated!

Btw, I'm a beginner and can only use simple python, so sad.

Comment: 10k data (ignoring the fact you haven't said what this is)/sec on a raspberry pi?

Comment: my brain has become fixated on this one. I just cannot comprehend how you can have a need to store so much info from something so ubiquitous, or what use it's going to be. Please give the context.

Comment: I‘m sorry for my  negligence, It's a piezoelectric sensor. I use it to do the footstep detection. The data from adc is a float data. The system must have a 'ns'-level precision so it needs so much data.

Comment: And you think RPi 4 hardware should be fast enough for this task?

Comment: I have tested. Reading 10k data could take about 0.8s. I can make a list and package them by pickle module  in 1s. But then do not know how to write them to influxdb in time.

Comment: Ignoring the rsp's performance, is there a solution to do that? So I could try it.

Comment: Ok, I can understand what the data is, but I have no idea why you'd need to store it like that. The number of observations is _huge_ and for what?

Comment: For the system must have ns precision.  In fact I have multiple nodes like this. To make sure their time is highly synchronized for each data.

Comment: @YouLee did you find a good solution for this? I have a very similar problem here too.

Answer (score 1):

InfluxDB OSS will process writes faster if you batch them. The [python client has a batch parameter](https://influxdb-python.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api-documentation.html#influxdb.InfluxDBClient.write_points) `batch_size` that you can use to do this. If you are reading ~10k points/s I would try a batch size of about 10k too. The batches should be compressed to speed transfer.

The `write` method also allows sending the tags `path=address,elementss=link` as a dictionary. Doing this should decrease parsing effort.

Are you also running InfluxDB on the raspberry pi or do you send the data off the Pi over a network connection?

I noticed that you said in the comments that nanosecond precision is very important but you did not include a timestamp in your line protocol point example. You should provide a timestamp yourself if the timing is this critical. Without an explicit timestamp in the data, InfluxDB will insert a timestamp at "when the data arrives" which is unpredictable.

As noted in the comments, you may want to consider preprocessing this data some before sending it to InfluxDB. We can't make a suggestion without knowing how you are processing the piezo data to detect footsteps. Usually ADC values are averaged in small batches (10 - 100 reads, depending) to reduce noise. Assuming your footstep detector runs continuously, you'll have over 750 million points per day from a *single* sensor. This is a lot of data to store and postprocess.

Please edit your question to include move information, if you are willing.

Comment: Yeah, Thank you for your advice. I wanna save the data in local influxdb on raspberry pi. The code above ist incomplete. I will notice the timestamp before saving in db.  I wonder if I should make a for/while loop and use the write method for each points. Or something else. I do not need preprocessing. Read and save 1w points/sec in influxdb is all my task.

Comment: `1w points/sec` - how much is "1w"? If my answer was helpful to you - please up vote it. Try the for loop and let us know. What was the influxdb error you were seeing what it was "too slow"?

Comment: Lol,my mistake,10k points/sec. I have voted.  I used the for loop to write 1000 points could take 10 seconds. Particularly strange, so I say it's too slow.

Comment: Yes, that is too slow for you. I might try this at home. Very interesting problem here.